# Serial communication arduino mega and D1 Wemos Mini

Tags: esp8266, arduino-mega, softwareserial

Can anyone help me connecting arduino mega to D1 Wemos Mini serially? Please let me know most efficient and easy steps to setup a communication.

Using that following tutorial:

https://engineeringprojectshub.com/serial-communication-between-nodemcu-and-arduino/amp/

Following is the circuit diagram: 
https://i.stack.imgur.com/oOKwL.png

Comment: Rx to Tx3 and Tx to RX3, gnd and 3.3 V. ready. in Mega in code use Serial3 to communicate with esp8266.

Comment: @Juraj Is the Wemos Mini 5V tolerant? Otherwise a voltage divider would be needed between Mega TX and Wemos RX

Comment: @AliHassanRaza What exactly is your problem with setting up the connection? Serial (aka UART) has only 2 lines plus ground connection. There are many tutorials on the web. Did they not help you? What exactly couldn't you understand there?

Comment: @chrisl, voltage divider would limit the speed and complicate troubleshooting.. the esp8266 can handle 5 V logic pull-up current for a test. in long term setup I recommend a level shifter, not voltage divider

Comment: I am not getting anything when I try to serially communicate them.

Comment: Then you need to show us your code and wiring. Please edit your question and add the information there, not in the comments, as the comments are only temporary

Comment: if (esp.available()>0)
  {
    Serial.println("Inside");
    int data = esp.read();
    Serial.println(data);
  }

It is not going inside this condition, neither at arduino side nor at esp side

Comment: Using that following tutorial:
https://engineeringprojectshub.com/serial-communication-between-nodemcu-and-arduino/amp/

Comment: what is esp? SoftwareSerial? use hardware Serial3 (or 1 or 2). SoftwareSerial doesn't work on all pins of Mega

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apart from ensuring you're wiring TX -> RX and connecting all grounds, you can use [SerialTransfer.h](https://github.com/PowerBroker2/SerialTransfer) to automatically packetize and parse your data for inter-Arduino communication without the headace. The library is installable through the Arduino IDE and includes many examples.

Here are the library's features:

> This library:
>
> - can be downloaded via the Arduino IDE's Libraries Manager (search "SerialTransfer.h")
> - works with "software-serial" libraries
> - is non blocking
> - uses packet delimiters
> - uses consistent overhead byte stuffing
> - uses CRC-8 (Polynomial 0x9B with lookup table)
> - allows the use of dynamically sized packets (packets can have payload lengths anywhere from 1 to 254 bytes)
> - can transfer bytes, ints, floats, and even structs!!

Example TX Arduino Sketch:

```
#include "SerialTransfer.h"

SerialTransfer myTransfer;

void setup()
{
  Serial.begin(115200);
  Serial1.begin(115200);
  myTransfer.begin(Serial1);
}

void loop()
{
  char buff[] = "hi";

  myTransfer.txObj(buff, sizeof(buff));
  myTransfer.sendData(sizeof(buff));
  delay(100);
}
```

Example RX Arduino Sketch:

```
#include "SerialTransfer.h"

SerialTransfer myTransfer;

void setup()
{
  Serial.begin(115200);
  Serial1.begin(115200);
  myTransfer.begin(Serial1);
}

void loop()
{
  if(myTransfer.available())
  {
    char buff[40];
    
    myTransfer.rxObj(buff, sizeof(buff));
    
    Serial.println("New Data: ");
    Serial.write(buff, sizeof(buff));
    Serial.println();
  }
  else if(myTransfer.status < 0)
  {
    Serial.print("ERROR: ");

    if(myTransfer.status == -1)
      Serial.println(F("CRC_ERROR"));
    else if(myTransfer.status == -2)
      Serial.println(F("PAYLOAD_ERROR"));
    else if(myTransfer.status == -3)
      Serial.println(F("STOP_BYTE_ERROR"));
  }
}
```